# SQL query to find record with ID not in another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables with binding primary keys in the database and I want to find a disjoint set between them. For example,

`Table1`

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Peter |
| 3 | Mary |

`Table2`

| ID | Address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | address2 |
| 2 | address2 |

So how do I create a SQL query so I can fetch the row with ID from `table1` that is not in `table2`? In this case, `(3, Mary)` should be returned.

**PS:** The ID is the primary key for those two tables.

Comment: As a tip for future questions: always define what database system (and which version of that database) you're using. *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* used by most database systems - that doesn't really help much ... often, databases have extensions and features way beyond the ANSI/ISO SQL Standard that make solving the problem easy - but for that, you need to tell us what database you're using

Comment: @marc_s: What if they're looking for a language-agnostic solution, because they need to support multiple underlying database systems, or the database implementation is abstracted away?

Comment: Hi @marc_s, I am using PostgreSQL in this case. Thanks for the reminding.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

Comment: @PrinceJea actually it depends. [*See here for clarification*](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)

Comment: When i have 20 datas, It works, but when i have 20000 datas, it not work, Iam confuse now.

Comment: No Idea why but it's not working. I have around 10000 rows to in table. In my case @JohnWoo 's solution worked just fine.

Comment: It's will not work we too many values in "Not In" since this method has a limited number of values   cf : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_maximum_number_of_sql_in_list_values.htm

Comment: I had to do it like this: select i from Table1
WHERE  i NOT IN (SELECT i FROM Table2 **where i is not null**) and i **is not null**

Comment: This should not be the answer of choice. Well... At least for Postgres, potentially for others RDBMS vendors. Pretty old but still gold: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Comment: ```SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE id IS NOT NULL```

Answer (score 159):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table1 a
            LEFT JOIN table2 b
                on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this is the faster approach for a very large database

Comment: I have about 500k rows in my tables and this ran instantly. Before finding this, I naively tried the accepted solution and still hadn't finished running after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 56):

There are basically 3 approaches to that: `not exists`, `not in` and `left join / is null`.

### LEFT JOIN with IS NULL

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    t_left l
LEFT JOIN
        t_right r
ON      r.value = l.value
WHERE   r.value IS NULL
```

### NOT IN

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    t_left l
WHERE   l.value NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  value
        FROM    t_right r
        )
```

### NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    t_left l
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    t_right r
        WHERE   r.value = l.value
        )
```

Which one is better? The answer to this question might be better to be broken down to major specific RDBMS vendors. Generally speaking, one should avoid using `select ... where ... in (select...)` when the magnitude of number of records in the sub-query is unknown. Some vendors might limit the size. Oracle, for example, has a [limit of 1,000](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_maximum_number_of_sql_in_list_values.htm). Best thing to do is to try all three and show the execution plan.

Specifically form PostgreSQL, execution plan of `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` are the same. I personally prefer the `NOT EXISTS` option because it shows better the intent. After all the semantic is that *you want to find records in A that its pk **do not exist** in B*.

Old but still gold, specific to PostgreSQL though: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/

Comment: I tied all 3 of these in my Stored Proc. The first suggestion (LEFT JOIN with IS NULL) was by far the fastest.

Answer (score 12):

### Fast Alternative

I ran some tests (on postgres 9.5) using two tables with ~2M rows each. This query below performed at least 5* better than the other queries proposed:

```
-- Count
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    (SELECT id FROM table1) EXCEPT (SELECT id FROM table2)
) t1_not_in_t2;

-- Get full row
SELECT table1.* FROM (
    (SELECT id FROM table1) EXCEPT (SELECT id FROM table2)
) t1_not_in_t2 JOIN table1 ON t1_not_in_t2.id=table1.id;
```

Comment: This was not faster than @Jhon Woo's solution. I am using Postgres 9.6 and with Jhon's solution runtime is about 60ms. While I quite this solution after 120 sec and no result.

Answer (score 6):

Keeping in mind the points made in @John Woo's comment/link above, this is how I typically would handle it:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name 
FROM   Table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 NULL
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tblA a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT b.ID FROM tblB b)    --For count


SELECT ID FROM tblA a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT b.ID FROM tblB b)    --For results
```