# Need to know how to select nonduplicates from a table based on a second table

Tags: sql, openoffice-base

I have a table called names-original with a numeric ID column.

I have another table called names-supplemental also with a numeric ID column.

These numeric IDs come from the same number space.

I need a query to extract the rows from names-supplemental that have no id match in names-original.

I come close to finding the answer on searches, but I'm not finding it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to find record with ID not in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table)

Comment: `not existts`.  `not in`.

Comment: If you go with `not in`, [be aware of NULL values](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  original.*  FROM    original  as original
        LEFT JOIN supplemental as supplemental on original.ID = supplemental.ID
WHERE   supplemental.ID IS NULL
```