# How to get records that exist in table 1 but not in table 2?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables: excluded and kaggleresults. I am trying to find records that exist in `excluded` but don't exist in `kaggleresults`

counts:

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from excluded").count()
res136: Long = 4652

scala> spark.sql("select * from kaggleresults").count()
res137: Long = 4635
```

The difference is `17`

```
scala> res136-res137
res139: Long = 17
```

I am trying to get those 17 records. I wrote the query below but it returns `38` instead.

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from excluded left join kaggleresults on kaggleresults.subject_id = excluded.subject_id where kaggleresults.subject_id is null").count()
res135: Long = 38
```

**Question**

What query do I need to write to get those 17 records?

Comment: please can you tell me the common id between these tables

Comment: Anthony your exclusion query looks right on.  You can do it via the left join like you have done, EXISTS, or NOT IN but all should produce the same results you likely got 38  because 38 records don't exist.  You are saying 17, but the one other variation that can happen is records that are in kagglersults that are NOT in excluded you likely have 21 records like that which would mean a net difference of 17

Comment: @Anthony please check the below query I think it will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the actual records (not the counts), you can use

```
SELECT * FROM excluded
WHERE subject_id NOT IN ( SELECT subject_id FROM kaggleresults )
```

However, you should not be surprised if the resultant row count does not match the difference of the two tables' individual row counts.

For example: suppose table1 has id's 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and table2 has id's 3, 4, 5, and 6. The row counts of table1 and of table2 are 5 and 4, respectively, for a difference of 1, but there are actually *two* records in table1 that have id's that do not exist in table2.

Comment: When i do the similar thing i get `mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 64)` error when i have it in spark.sql how do i fix it ?

Answer (score 9):

Isn't it a case for **LEFT_ANTI** join?

```
scala> val excluded = (0 to 5).toDS
left: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> val kaggleresults = (3 to 10).toDS
right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> excluded.join(kaggleresults, Seq("value"), "leftanti").show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    0|
|    1|
|    2|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

using not in key word
You can use the below query

```
Select * from excluded where subject_id not in (select subject_id from  kaggleresults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Not In` syntax along with a subquery.

```
SELECT ID, Name 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

[SQL query to find record with ID not in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table#12048676)