# How to displaying data from database [MySQL Query]

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are related

that table is `teachers` and `attendance`

that 2 tables, is related with field `teachers.id` and `attendance.id_teachers`

now my question is, how to displaying `teachers` data which is that teachers data (`teachers.id`) is not listed in `attendance` table

i hope you guys understand what i'm hoping for...

I appreciate every answer

thanks

Comment: Below link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_teachers FROM attendance)
```

Answer (score 0):

**IN** clause is your friend here. You may want to read-up on this. Following query should give the result:

`select * from teachers
where id not in (select id_teachers from attendance)`