# find the code in table A which does not have in table B for particular gr_code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table in my same DB

```
create table a(gr_code nvarchar, code int)
insert into a values('1',100),('0',200),('1',200),('0',100)

create table b(gr_code nvarchar, code int)
insert into b values('1',100),('0',200)
```

find the code in table A which does not have in table B for particular gr_code

```
 expected result:
 gr_code    code
 1          200
 0          100
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to find record with ID not in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple using the clause exists

```
select * 
from a 
where not exists (select * 
                  from b 
                  where b.gr_code = a.gr_code and 
                        b.code = a.code)
```

This returns the result on your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

```
select a.* 
from a 
left join b on a.gr_code = b.gr_code and a.code = b.code
where b.gr_code is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.gr_code = b.gr_code
WHERE b.gr_code IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) like so:

```
select * 
from a 
except  
select * 
from b
```