# SQL select id where id is not in a entry with multiple id in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database and I desire to select all id from first table where this id is not in an entry of the second table.

For example :

- Table1 has columns (ID, Name) and sample data: (1, "John"), (2, "Peter"), ... , (333, "Mary"), (433, "Rosa")
- Table2 has columns (ID_not_like_Table1, IDs) and sample data: (123, "1;2;433"), (124, "2;433"), (125, "1;433"), (126, "1;433")

In this case, ID 333 should be returned because 333 is never in IDs from Table2

So how do I create a SQL query so I can fetch the row with ID from Table1 that is not in IDs from Table2 ?

If it can be done in one query, i can do it in more in a php file.

PS: this topic is inspired from this one : [SQL query to find record with ID not in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table)

Thanks in advance to any help

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: (1) Fix your data structure.  Do not store lists of ids in delimited strings.  That is wrong.  You should be using a junction table.  (2) You need a database tag.

Comment: When talking about tables in a relational database, it's better to present sample data **also** as [a table](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table) - or as SQL Scripts or even better as a [SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)

Comment: so, i'm using mysql and it's not my database so i'm stuck with this data structure :(

Answer (score 2):

Do not store lists of ids in a string.  That is wrong.  Wrong.  Wrong.  Wrong.  Why?

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- SQL has really poor string processing functions.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL engines cannot optimize string operations.
- SQL has this really great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.

That said, sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  There are approaches to take.  You haven't specified your database, but in standard SQL you can do:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where ';' || t2.ids || ';' like '%;' || cast(t1.id as varchar(255)) || ';%';
```

This is only suggested as a work-around when you cannot fix the data model.

EDIT:

MySQL uses the `concat()` function.  And, you might want to take unexpected spaces into account:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where concat(';', replace(t2.ids, ' ', ''), ';') like concat('%;', cast(t1.id as varchar(255)), ';%');
```

Comment: (And that's leaving aside any formatting differences that might play such as 1- vs. -1 or accidental additional spaces.)

Comment: Thanks to you and yes that's not my own database and i have to deal with it :(