# Java display records from a table based on records in other tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, netbeans

I'm very new to using databases and SQL in general and I'm having some trouble figuring out a function that will allow me to display records from a table in my jdbc database based on data from other tables in the database. I will illustrate below:

Example of "DEMANDS" table (column headers, "ID" is the primary key):

```
NAME|ADDRESS|DESTINATION|DATE|TIME|ID
```

Example of "DRIVERS" table ("REGISTRATION" is the primary key):

```
USERNAME|PASSWORD|REGISTRATION|NAME
```

Example of "JOURNEY" table ("JID" is the primary key,"REGISTRATION" is a foreign key)

```
JID|NAME|ADDRESS|DESTINATION|DISTANCE|REGISTRATION|DATE|TIME|STATUS
```

Below is the code that I have that is used to display tables on a jsp file:

```
public String retrieve(String query) throws SQLException {
    select(query);
    return makeTable(rsToList());//results;
}

private void select(String query){        
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        //statement.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("way way"+e);
        //results = e.toString();
    }
}

private String makeTable(ArrayList list) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    String[] row;
    b.append("<table border=\"3\">");
    for (Object s : list) {
      b.append("<tr>");
      row = (String[]) s;
        for (String row1 : row) {
            b.append("<td>");
            b.append(row1);
            b.append("</td>");
        }
      b.append("</tr>\n");
    } // for
    b.append("</table>");
    return b.toString();
}//makeHtmlTable

private ArrayList rsToList() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); //number of column
    String columnName[] = new String[count];

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        columnName[i-1] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
    }
    aList.add(columnName);

    int cols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) { 
      String[] s = new String[cols];
      for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
        s[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
      } 
      aList.add(s);
    } // while    
    return aList;
} //rsToList
```

All of this code works fine and if I pass in a query into the "Retrieve" function such as:

```
String query = "select * from DRIVERS";
```

It will display all of the records of the "DRIVERS" table.

What I am wanting to do though, is only list drivers from the driver table that are available at the time specified in the demand (meaning their registration is not currently in a record in the journey table at the same time as the demand) If possible, I would also only like to display the "NAME" and "REGISTRATION" columns as oppose to the whole record.

I would really appreciate some help with this as I've searched around for solutions for quite some time and have not been able to work out a function that will achieve the desired outcome.

Cheers,

Creation of tables script:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--DROP Table Demands;
CREATE TABLE Demands (
  Name varchar(20),
  Address varchar(60),
  Destination varchar(60),
  Date date DEFAULT NULL,
  Time time DEFAULT NULL,
  Status varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  id INT primary key
);


-- --------------------------------------------------------
--DROP Table Drivers;
CREATE TABLE Drivers (
  username varchar(20),
  password varchar(20),
  Registration varchar(10),
  Name varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (Registration)
);


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--DROP Table Journey;
CREATE TABLE Journey (
  jid INT primary key
  Destination varchar(60),
  Distance integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  Registration varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Date date NOT NULL,
  Time time DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to find record with ID not in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048633/sql-query-to-find-record-with-id-not-in-another-table). Please remember to do research before asking questions here. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you provide the creation script of your model (CREATE TABLE statements)?

Comment: @Ahmad Shahwan I will edit my post to show this, cheers!

Comment: I updated my answer according to your creation script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query may answer your question.

```
SELECT Drivers.Name, Drivers.Registration
FROM Drivers
LEFT JOIN Journey ON Journey.Registration = Drivers.Registration
LEFT JOIN Demands ON Demands.Date = Journey.Date
WHERE Demands.id IS NULL;
```

This joins JOURNEY and DRIVER based on the foreign key relation. It then outer-joins DEMANDS and JOURNEY based on an implicit relation that is `DATE`. Finally we only keep records that fail the outer join condition.

The model has a major flaw though as the relation between DEMANDS and JOURNEY is based on a field of type Date, as far as one can tell by what your provided.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Would you recommend that I maybe include a foreign key in JOURNEY that references the ID in DEMANDS? Would that be a better solution?

Comment: If you have a one-to-many relationship, yes (that is each journey has only one demand). Otherwise (a journey may have one or more demand) you would have to create a new table that "breaks" the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I tried to pass in the query as you stated however, I got an error that says "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Your `NullPointerException` may be due to a null value in your tables, ex. name in Driver.

Comment: Hey, your updated query no longer gives the error however, it doesn't actually display any drivers. For example, I have 3 drivers in the driver table, one record in DEMAND where the TIME is "10:30" and 1 record in JOURNEY for TIME "09:30", should it not display all 3 drivers as none of them are in JOURNEY for a time "10:30"? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: I also tried changing part of the query to specify time instead of date, e.g. "Demands on Demands.Time = Journey.Time" as I thought maybe this was the issue however this did not fix the problem

Comment: If you want to show drivers that have no corresponding Journeys, you need convert the first join into an outer-join (add LEFT to JOIN Journey statement) as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comments, I implemented your query incorrectly, I have now implemented it correctly and it works perfectly! I really appreciate the help as i'm completely new to all this SQL and relational database business and what you've shown me has helped me grasp some concepts a little better